# Show that the polynomial ring $F[X]$ is not a free product in the category of associative algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that

> If $F$ is a field and $X$ is a set with $|X|>1$, then $F[X]$ is not a free object in the category of associative $F-$ algebras.

Now here is my attempt. Apparently, I got stuck so I am not sure how to proceed from what have. I never prove an object is not a free object.

> Assume on the contrary that $F[X]$ is a free object. Let $A$ be an (noncommutative) associative $R-$algebra. Then since $F[X]$ is a free object, then there exists an associative algebra homomorphism $\gamma$ making the diagram commutates. Since the set function $i \colon X \to F(X)$ is unknown, it is hard for me to construct the set function $g \colon X \to A$ in order to get a contradiction. Also, I don't know many examples of noncommutative associative algebras $A$. I think it will be nice to construct a specific $A$. I think the idea is to contradict the idea that $A$ is noncommutative. But again, I got very stuck. I haven't thought about the second part of the questions yet. Any hint will be great. Thanks!

Comment: The free (associative) algebra on one generator is the polynomial algebra in one variable, and the free algebra on more than one generator is noncommutative. That's enough to conclude.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan After googling the free-associative algebra on more generators, I think you are right. I know a lot of places on the internet mention that elements in $X$ don't commutate with each other so the free (associative) algebra is not commutative when $|X| > 1$. But assuming that someone never learns about free (associative) algebra and only knows what associative algebra and free objects are, how can we conclude that free (associative) algebra is noncommutative?

Comment: By the universal property, it suffices to show that there exists some noncommutative algebra (really!). Then you can map into it, sending two distinct elements of $X$ to two elements which don't commute.

Comment: In other words, if the free algebra on two generators is commutative, then every pair of elements in every algebra must commute, which is of course ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, I want to clear up the definition a bit. You said:

> Since the set function $i:X \longrightarrow F[X]$ is unknown, it is hard for me to construct the set function $g:X \longrightarrow A$ in order to get a contradiction.

The function $i$ is actually not unknown. The issue here is a slight abuse of notation in the problem statement. You are asked to show that $F[X]$ is not free on $X$ in this category, but this is not entirely accurate. Look back at your definition of a free object. It would really be more correct to say that $i: X \longrightarrow F$ is free, rather than to say $F$ is free. The map $i$ is part of the data here, as it does not make sense to say that an object in isolation is free. A more precise statement of the problem would be to show that $i: X \longrightarrow F[X]$ is not free, where $i(x) = x$.

To belabor this point a bit more, let's instead consider $F[X]$ in the category of commutative $F$-algebras. Here we do have that $i: X \longrightarrow F[X]$ as given is free. However, if I chose a different map $j: X \longrightarrow F[X]$ I could contradict this. For instance, I could have some $j(x_0) = 0$. Then I could consider a map $X \longrightarrow F$ sending $x_0 \mapsto 1$. By universal property, we would then need a map $F[X] \longrightarrow F$ sending $0 \mapsto 1$, which is impossible. The point of this example was to emphasize that we really do need to have the map $i$ as part of the initial data. We cannot simply take an object and ask if it's free.

Anyways, back to the problem at hand. Let $F\langle X\rangle$ denote the ring of *noncommutative* polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in $F$. That is, an element of this ring is a formal $F$-linear combination of terms like $x_1^{e_1} \cdots x_n^{e_n}$. We are *not* assuming that the $x_i$ commute. So in particular, take $x_0 \neq x_1$ in $X$, as we assumed $|X| > 1$. Then $x_0x_1 \neq x_1x_0$ in $F\langle X\rangle$.

Let's consider now the map $g: X \longrightarrow F\langle X\rangle$ via $g(x) = x$. Then if $F[X]$ (meaning $i: X \longrightarrow F[X]$) was free, we would have a map $\overline g: F[X] \longrightarrow F\langle X\rangle$ such that $\overline g \circ i = g$. Thus, $\overline{g}(x_0x_1) = x_0 x_1 \in F\langle X\rangle$. However, in $F[X]$ the variables commute so $x_1x_0=\overline{g}(x_1x_0) = \overline{g}(x_0x_1) = x_0 x_1$, a contradiction. Thus, $i: X \longrightarrow F[X]$ is not free on $X$ in this category.